# Embed all the upcoming events that happening in my city to my website by using eventbrite api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, eventbrite

I am trying to post all the upcoming event that is happening in Vancouver city to my website
https://www.eventbrite.ca/d/canada--vancouver/all-events/

I am unable to find any endpoint with location.
What is the venue id of Vancouver city?

Here is my code in the controller

```
def blogs
    require 'net/http'
require 'uri'


uri = URI.parse("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/94269567815/?expand=ticket_classes")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request["Authorization"] = "Bearer xxx"

req_options = {
use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
http.request(request)

end

body = JSON.parse(response.body)

@body = body

end
```

in the view

```
<%= @body.inspect %>
```

Comment: You should check the docs properly. I doubt somebody can help you out here putting efforts for you.

Comment: I checked but I am not sure if eventbrite have this option!